# Having trouble recompiling ROS Source / What to do when you have two versions of ROS installed?

Tags: ros, rosout, compile, catkin, bashrc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good morning,

I have successfully installed ROS Indigo from source following the instructions at:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

Everything works great as far as I can tell, the installation succeed without errors. I am trying to verify that I am running off of the source install rather than the installation I had on my computer previously(regular indigo v. source indigo). I attempted to test this by editing a std:cout in rosout.cpp so that I would see a change at the beginning of a log after I recompiled. It did not change though.

This is how I recompiled after making the changes to rosout.cpp:

```
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --pkg rosout --force-cmake
```

Then I ran:

```
roscore
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key
```

to regenerate some log files. The log files did not change though which leads me to believe that I didn't compile the source code correctly, or I a not running my turtlesim example off of the source installation.

Some Info:

```
dev@dev-VirtualBox:/opt$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

I am not sure how to confirm / solve those issues. Does anyone know if I should be adding something to my bashrc?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257530/having-trouble-recompiling-ros-source-/-what-to-do-when-you-have-two-versions-of-ros-installed?/) by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [corcorant](https://answers.ros.org/users/29721/corcorant/) on 2017-03-21**:
At the bottom of my bashrc file, I found this line:

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

and replaced it with

```
source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
```

Everything works great now. Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2017-03-21**:
Cool, I converted my comment to an answer. Please mark it as accepted when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you are not sourcing the `/opt/ros/.../setup.bash` file in your `~/.bashrc`. Then make sure you source the result of your workspace, like `source /path/to/catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2